# Is there a MaxAbsScaler in SparkR (Spark 2.1.0 or 2.2.0)?

Tags: r, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, preprocessor, sparkr

In spark, there are StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler, MaxAbsScaler in scala, java and python. Does Spark have methods like these in R (SparkR) ?

Answer (score 2):

In Spark 2.2.0 or 2.1.0 there are available scalers which are necessary in data pre-processing in scala, java and python. But there are no available scalers yet in R (SparkR).Therefore, i wrote two functions that scale data frame columns.

**Function 1 :**

```
# max abs scaler function (R dataframe to Spark Dataframe)
maxabsscaler <- function(df, cols, scalingUpperLimit){
  for(i in cols){
    max <- max(df[i])
    df[i] <- (df[, c(i)] / max) * scalingUpperLimit
  }
  return(as.DataFrame(df))
}
```

**Function 2 :**

```
# max abs scaler function (Only Spark Dataframe)
maxabsscaler2 <- function(df, cols, scalingUpperLimit){
  createOrReplaceTempView(df, "df_tmp")
  for(i in columns){
    max <- collect(sql(paste("SELECT MAX(", i ,") FROM df_tmp")))[[1]]
    df[[i]] <- df[[i]] / max * scalingUpperLimit
  }
  return(df)
}
```

**Note :** Function1 is suitable for your desktop application or test environment because when you call this function you need to convert spark data frame to R data frame. R data frame runs on single computer. So, it is not suitable for big data sets. In Function2, there is no necessity for converting spark data frame to R data frame. Therefore, you can deploy this function to your production environment. Functions cannot handle NA values. But you can improve them.You need to specify columns and scalingUpperLimit (100, 10, 1 and so on) parameter.

**Sample Usage :**

```
survival_of_patients <- read.df("D:\\projects\\R\\data\\survival_of_patients.csv", "csv", header = "true")

trainTest <-randomSplit(survival_of_patients, c(0.8, 0.2), 42)
train = trainTest[[1]]
test = trainTest[[2]]

columns <- colnames(as.data.frame(train))[!colnames(as.data.frame(train)) %in% c("SurvivalStatus")]

train <- maxabsscaler(as.data.frame(train), columns,  10)
test <- maxabsscaler(as.data.frame(test), columns,  10)

# or
# train <- maxabsscaler2(train, columns,  10)
# test <- maxabsscaler2(test, columns,  10)
```

You can download this data set and test the functions. 
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Haberman%27s+Survival